# How to get button's value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, jquery-events

I want to check if the button the user clicks is correct then I will do something. To do that I use an if statement to check if the value of the button matches the "correct" property in the "questions" array. So far I have tried these solutions and none of them work:

```
if (e.target.tagName === "BUTTON" && e.target.innerText === questions[i].correct) {

alert("correct"); /* testing */
}
```

```
if (e.target.tagName === "BUTTON" && e.target.textContent === questions[i].correct) {

alert("correct"); /* testing */
}
```

```
if (e.target.tagName === "BUTTON" && e.target.value === questions[i].correct) {

alert("correct"); /* testing */
}
```

```
if (e.target.tagName === "BUTTON" && e.target.innerHTML === questions[i].correct) {

alert("correct"); /* testing */
}
```

Here is the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Quiz Game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quiz.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <p>Question <span class="qtn-count">1</span> of 5</p>
            <p>Score: 0</p>
            <p id="question"></p>
            <div id="btns-wrapper">
                <button class="btn"></button>
                <button class="btn"></button>
                <button class="btn"></button>
                <button class="btn"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn" id="start-btn">Start</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="quiz.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #E987FF;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #E987FF 0%, #B7DB81 50%, #FFEBEB 100%);
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #E987FF 0%, #B7DB81 50%, #FFEBEB 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #E987FF 0%, #B7DB81 50%, #FFEBEB 100%);
}

#question {
    font-size: 20px;
    flex-grow: 4;
    text-align: center;
}


.btn {
    background: rgb(240,248,255);
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.44);
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 50px;
    width: 90%;
}
#btns-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 90%;
    height: 50vh;

}

#wrapper {
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 2px 17px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.15); 
box-shadow: 4px 2px 17px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
width: 90%;
font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
background: #61FF68;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #61FF68 0%, #4AC44F 50%, #6BFF98 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #61FF68 0%, #4AC44F 50%, #6BFF98 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #61FF68 0%, #4AC44F 50%, #6BFF98 100%);
display: none;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 760px) {

#wrapper {
    width: 50%;
}


#btns-wrapper {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}

.btn {
    width: 40%;
}

#question {
font-size: 30px;

}


}
```

And the JavaScript:

```
const questions = [

{

question: "What is 2 + 2?",

answers: [3,4,2,5],

correct: 4
},
{

question: "What is 5 + 2?",

answers: [7,3,2,2],

correct: 7
},
{

question: "What is 10 + 20?",

answers: [35,40,24,30],

correct: 30
},
{

question: "What is 2 + 3?",

answers: [1,7,2,5],

correct: 5
}

]


const btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")
const btns_wrapper = document.getElementById("btns-wrapper");
const qtn = document.getElementById("question");
let i=0;
const start_btn = document.getElementById("start-btn");
const content = document.getElementById("wrapper");



start_btn.addEventListener("click" , ()=> {

content.style.display = "block";
start_btn.style.display = "none";
qtn.textContent = questions[i].question



btn[0].textContent = questions[0].answers[0];
btn[1].textContent = questions[0].answers[1];
btn[2].textContent = questions[0].answers[2];
btn[3].textContent = questions[0].answers[3];


i++;
});



btns_wrapper.addEventListener("click" , (e)=> {

    if (e.target.tagName === "BUTTON" && e.target.innerText === questions[i].correct) {

alert("correct"); /* testing */
}

qtn.textContent = questions[i].question;


btn[0].textContent = questions[i].answers[0];
btn[1].textContent = questions[i].answers[1];
btn[2].textContent = questions[i].answers[2];
btn[3].textContent = questions[i].answers[3];


    i++;


});
```

Also when I click the button after the last question I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'correct' of undefined
>       at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (quiz.js:69)

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
if(questions[i].question === undefined) {

/* do Something */
}
```

Comment: Poor design. You are running a click Event on the button wrapper? What for? Just run it on each button. Why test for `e.target.tagName === "BUTTON" && e.target.innerText === questions[i].correct` when you already have an Array of answers that match up to the buttons... in other words you can just test for the index. Personally, I would use a Constructor so you can create each button quiz, very easily, with each one being a `new` instance.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Please note that i am a beginner in web development. This is not how my final code is going to look like. I am just testing to see if it works after that i will make some changes and refactor it to object oriented style."Just run it on each button". Do you mean to attach an event listener to each button? I attached an event listener to the  btns_wrapper because i want check if the answer is correct then i will do something like make the background green and go to next question at the same time. Please tell me if there are any other suggestions to improve my code.

Comment: You already have access to the parent without having an Event Listener on it. You just need to add, remove, or toggle a class on `btns_wrapper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.The `i++` in your `start_btn` click make the index of questions wrong after start.

2.The `i++` in your `btns_wrapper` click should be before assigning text to html.

3.`e.target.innerText` is string but `questions[i].correct` is number so the compare should be `e.target.innerText === questions[i].correct.toString()` or `e.target.innerText == questions[i].correct`.

Working version:

```js
const questions = [

{

question: "What is 2 + 2?",

answers: [3,4,2,5],

correct: 4
},
{

question: "What is 5 + 2?",

answers: [7,3,2,2],

correct: 7
},
{

question: "What is 10 + 20?",

answers: [35,40,24,30],

correct: 30
},
{

question: "What is 2 + 3?",

answers: [1,7,2,5],

correct: 5
}

]


const btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")
const btns_wrapper = document.getElementById("btns-wrapper");
const qtn = document.getElementById("question");
let i=0;
const start_btn = document.getElementById("start-btn");
const content = document.getElementById("wrapper");



start_btn.addEventListener("click" , ()=> {

content.style.display = "block";
start_btn.style.display = "none";
qtn.textContent = questions[i].question



btn[0].textContent = questions[i].answers[0];
btn[1].textContent = questions[i].answers[1];
btn[2].textContent = questions[i].answers[2];
btn[3].textContent = questions[i].answers[3];

});



btns_wrapper.addEventListener("click" , (e)=> {
    if (e.target.tagName === "BUTTON" && e.target.innerText === questions[i].correct.toString()) {

alert("correct"); /* testing */
}
i++;
qtn.textContent = questions[i].question;


btn[0].textContent = questions[i].answers[0];
btn[1].textContent = questions[i].answers[1];
btn[2].textContent = questions[i].answers[2];
btn[3].textContent = questions[i].answers[3];



});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #E987FF;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #E987FF 0%, #B7DB81 50%, #FFEBEB 100%);
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #E987FF 0%, #B7DB81 50%, #FFEBEB 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #E987FF 0%, #B7DB81 50%, #FFEBEB 100%);
}

#question {
    font-size: 20px;
    flex-grow: 4;
    text-align: center;
}


.btn {
    background: rgb(240,248,255);
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.44);
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 50px;
    width: 90%;
}
#btns-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 90%;
    height: 50vh;

}

#wrapper {
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 2px 17px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.15); 
box-shadow: 4px 2px 17px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
width: 90%;
font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
background: #61FF68;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #61FF68 0%, #4AC44F 50%, #6BFF98 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #61FF68 0%, #4AC44F 50%, #6BFF98 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #61FF68 0%, #4AC44F 50%, #6BFF98 100%);
display: none;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 760px) {

#wrapper {
    width: 50%;
}


#btns-wrapper {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}

.btn {
    width: 40%;
}

#question {
font-size: 30px;

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Quiz Game</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <p>Question <span class="qtn-count">1</span> of 5</p>
            <p>Score: 0</p>
            <p id="question"></p>
            <div id="btns-wrapper">
                <button class="btn"></button>
                <button class="btn"></button>
                <button class="btn"></button>
                <button class="btn"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn" id="start-btn">Start</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any solution for the last part of my question?

Comment: you can simply check if i >= questions.length then do something to handle it because when i >= questions.length, `questions[i]` become `undefined`. That causes the error.

Comment: Thank you once again last question Can you explain how the i++ in the start_btn make the question index go wrong

Comment: first you set the html to represent `questions[0]` and then `i++` make `i` become 1. So when you check the answer, you compare `questions[0]` choice to `questions[1].correct`